# keepalived script makes failover go insane

Tags: python, python-2.7

**What happens?**
When i start keepalived all works fine. When node01 fails and it cannot start postgresql anymore it will constantly try to force an election. Even if the postgresql cannot start. The election happens every second now.

**What i want to achieve**
It should check if postgresql can be started on node01 when node02 is the master, but not force an election all the time. Can someone try to help and get it right?

**This is my code**

stop-pgsql:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

sys.exit(
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'stop', 'postgresql.service'])
)
```

notify:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

state = sys.argv[3]

with open('/var/run/keepalived.pgsql.state', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(state)

if state == 'MASTER':
    sys.exit(
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'start', 'postgresql.service'])
    )

if state == 'BACKUP':
    sys.exit(
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'stop', 'postgresql.service'])
    )

if state == 'FAULT':
    sys.exit(
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'stop', 'postgresql.service'])
    )
```

check-pgsql:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
from time import sleep

sleep(1)

with open('/var/run/keepalived.pgsql.state', 'r') as f:
    state = f.read().strip().strip("\n")

# status 0: Postgresql is running
# status 3: Postgresql has been stopped
status = subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'status', 'postgresql.service'])

if status == 0 and state == 'MASTER':
    sys.exit(0)

if status == 0 and state == 'BACKUP':
    sys.exit(3)

if status == 3 and state == 'MASTER':
    sys.exit(3)

if status == 3 and state == 'BACKUP':
    sys.exit(0)
```

keepalived config:

```
vrrp_script chk_pgsql {
  script       "/etc/keepalived/check-pgsql"
  interval 1
  fall 3
  rise 3
  weight -4
}

vrrp_instance pgsql_vip {
    state EQUAL
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 4
    priority 100(node01)|99{node02}
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    track_script {
        chk_pgsql
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.20
    }
    notify "/etc/keepalived/notify"
    notify_stop "/etc/keepalived/stop"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After node01 dies, node02 gets elected master. Then, node01 gets checked by your check script. The script sees that node01 is now in the BACKUP state and posgresql is stopped, and returns 0. After the check script returns 0 3 times (based on your VRRP config), node01 thinks it is OK. Then, since node01 has higher priority than node02, it takes control through the election process. Then the check script fails because node01 is in MASTER state and posgresql is stopped. This causes keepalived to start flapping between nodes.

I think you could solve this in one of 2 ways:

1. make node01 and node02 equal priority
2. change your check script to just return the status of posgresql